# .aar Binding Library missing references in original project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, aar

I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-an-aar/) to build a binding library based off an AAR. I've added the .aar under the Jars folder in a new Java Bindings Library project. I set the build action to LibraryProjectZip. When I try to build I get errors telling me `The type or namespace name 'BasicWebViewClient' does not exist'`, however, this file is in the original project. When I browse the .aar, it's not there. Anyone know why the class wouldn't be included?

Thanks

Comment: Decompile the `classes.jar` inside the `.aar` and figure out why this type might not be included. Perhaps you're missing a reference?

Comment: I decompiled `classes.jar` and the file that is missing when I build the `.aar` in Visual Studio is present.

Comment: Have you double checked that all references to this `.aar` are included? That is, does your final `.dll` strip out many classes that have a dependency?

Comment: I was able to get the problem resolved following this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550891/java-binding-the-type-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-are-you-miss  -  however I'm left with one error saying that there's an inherited member not implemented..which is implemented in the original project. I think all these issues are from how Visual Studio is translating the project from Java to C#.